# firebase - Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.undefined.profileImageUrl'

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am a newbie to firebase and Javascript and I have tried many methods to get the user data store by the `user.uid` but all I'm getting is the data is being stored under "undefined".
[image]

[image]

```js
var displayName;
var userInfo;
var profile_url;

   $("#login-btn").click(function(){
     userInfo = firebase.auth().currentUser;
     if (userInfo) { 
       firebase.auth().signOut(); 
     } else { 
       var email = document.getElementById('login_email').value; 
       var password = document.getElementById('login_pw').value; 

       firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(){
         document.getElementById('login_bar').style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById('logout_bar').style.display = "inline-block"; 
         document.getElementById('userinfo_bar').style.display = "inline-block"; 
         document.getElementById('secession_bar').style.display = "inline-block";
         alert("login success");
         location.replace('board.html');
       }).catch(function(error) {

         var errorCode = error.code;
         var errorMessage = error.message;

         if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
           alert('wrong-password.');
         }

         else {
           alert(errorMessage);
         }
         console.log(errorMessage);

       }); 


     } 

   });

   $("#join-btn").click(function(){ 
     var email = document.getElementById('join_email').value;
     var password = document.getElementById('join_pw').value;
     var displayName = document.getElementById('join_name').value;
     var job = $('input[name=job]:checked').val();

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {

      var u_Ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid);

      userInfo = user;

      u_Ref.set({
        'email' : email,
        'job': job,
        'profileImageUrl':profile_url,
        'uid' : user.uid,
        'username': displayName
      });


        handleFileSelect(); 
        alert("join success");

    }, function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  alert(error);
});

     if (email.length < 4) {
       alert('x');
       return;
     }
     if (password.length < 4) {
       alert('x');
       return;
     }

    function initApp() {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) { 
          var displayName = user.displayName;
          var email = user.email;
          var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
          var photoURL = user.photoURL;
          var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
          var uid = user.uid;
          var providerData = user.providerData;

          user.updateProfile ({
            displayName : displayName,

          }). then (function () {
            console.log ( 'success');
          }). catch (function (error) {
            console.log( 'no');
          });

          userInfo = user;

          firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION); 
          document.getElementById('login_bar').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('logout_bar').style.display = "inline-block"; 
          document.getElementById('userinfo_bar').style.display = "inline-block";
          document.getElementById('secession_bar').style.display = "inline-block";


          $("#secession_bar").click(function(){
            user.delete().then(function(){ 
              alert('success');
             userRef= firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid);
             userRef.remove(); 
             firebase.storage().ref().child('userImages/' + userInfo.uid).delete(); 
            location.reload();
            });
          });

          $("#logout_bar").click(function(){
            firebase.auth().signOut();
            location.reload();
          });



        } else { 

          document.getElementById('login_bar').style.display = "inline-block"; 
          document.getElementById('logout_bar').style.display = "none"; 
          document.getElementById('userinfo_bar').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('secession_bar').style.display = "none";



        } 

      });
    } 

    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      evt.preventDefault();
      var file = evt.target.files[0];

      var metadata = {
        'contentType': file.type
      };


      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('userImages/' +userInfo.uid);

      storageRef.put(file, metadata).then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log('Uploaded', snapshot.totalBytes, 'bytes.');
        console.log('File metadata:', snapshot.metadata);

        snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
          console.log('File available at', url);
          profile_url = url;

        });
      }).catch(function(error) {

        console.error('Upload failed:', error);

      });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I spotted a thing in your code, `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method returns a promise which is of type [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#usercredential), an object that contains a structure of *credential* and *user*, So you've made a mistake in there by asking of property ***uid*** of ***user*** (the returned promise) which is non-existence.

it should looks like this:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(credential) {

      var userInfo = creadential.user;

      var u_Ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userInfo.uid);

      u_Ref.set({
        'email' : email,
        'job': job,
        'profileImageUrl':profile_url,
        'uid' : userIfo.uid,
        'username': displayName
      });
```

Comment: @LiOptt in that case you probably have some issue with initialization of firebase in general, because credential is not being assigned by you, it is the returned promise of the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method and it should be available for you after calling the method and waiting to be resolved.